# creating a SharePoint Lookup field via CSOM error

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am attempting to create a lookup field on a list using CSOM.   I have the Lookup vales defined in a ListTemplateType.GenericList named “User Status Types”.  This setup appears fine and I can successfully create the field against this list in SharePoint itself.

The problem comes when I try to create the field on the target list (a column that references the lookup values in the generic list mentioned above).

I am submitting the following Xml via fieldCollection(xml, false, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes)

```
<Field Type="Lookup" DisplayName="UserStatus" Description="System Activation Status" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="Lists/User Status Types" WebId="~sitecollection" Overwrite="TRUE" PrependId="TRUE" ShowField="Title" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" StaticName="Status" Name="Status" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
```

This list generates a ServerException “Value does not fall withing the expected range.”

Note that while referencing the list via the friendly name is ideal, I also have quick access to the Guid at any time.  I’m also interested in the pitfalls of using a named reference as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, in this case of using CSOM/c# client side, ends up being a combination of simplifying the XML and relying on post-add CSOM interactions.

In short, the above XML can be simplified to:

```
var lookupFieldXml = "<Field DisplayName="UserStatus" Type="Lookup" />";
var field = destinationList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(lookupFieldXml, false, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
lookupField = context.CastTo<FieldLookup>(field);
lookupField.LookupList = sourceLookupList.Id.ToString();
lookupField.LookupField = "Title";
// at this point, we can update against lookupField or field. It doesn't appear to matter.
field.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

A note about this solution - the key piece here is the explicit CastTo operator hanging off of the context. It is not a type-safe cast, you can cast any field to any other type of field and there are no complaints.

Comment: So helpful! FYI, if you want to control the StaticName of the field, you can set that as the DisplayName, Update(), and then set the display name to whatever you actually want it to be and Update() again. DisplayName is required so you can't get around it.